# WTForms: Disable client-side validation on cancel

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms, flask-bootstrap

What I'm asking for is actually quite simple. I want to create a form with some fields and a *submit* and a *cancel* button. I want to use the `quick_form` template function of Flask-Bootstrap to keep overhead in my template low. My form looks like this:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.validators import Required, Length


class SequenceForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name:', validators=[Required(), Length(1, 128)])

    # some other fields here

    submit = SubmitField('submit')
    cancel = SubmitField('cancel')
```

The template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          {{ wtf.quick_form(form, button_map={'submit': 'primary'}) }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As one would suspect I want to validate and accept the input values on *submit* and skip validation on *cancel*. So my view function looks as expected.

```
@main.route('sequence/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sequence():
    form = SequenceForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'submit' in request.form:
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                print(form.duration.data)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('sequence.html', form=form)
```

Now if *cancel* is pressed there should logically be no validation and the redirect should take place. However I run into the issue that my view function doesn't even get called if I press either *submit* or *cancel* due to the client-side validation.

```
<input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required="" type="text" value="">
```

Is there a way to disable client-side validation on WTForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Required](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/validators.html#wtforms.validators.Required) validator as well as the [DataRequired](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#wtforms.validators.DataRequired) and [InputRequired](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#wtforms.validators.InputRequired) which replace `Required` since version 3 of WTForms set the *replace* flag of the field. This flag is used to add the *required* attribute to the HTML representation of the field. My workaround is to manually create a validate function.

```
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

def _required(form, field):
    if not field.raw_data or not field.raw_data[0]:
        raise ValidationError('Field is required')

class SequenceForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name:', validators=[_required, Length(1, 128)])

    # some other fields here

    submit = SubmitField('submit')
    cancel = SubmitField('cancel')
```

This way there is no validation on the client-side and it is ensured that the view function is called on every *submit* or *cancel*.

**Note**

An even simpler solution is to subclass the `InputRequired` validator and overwrite the field_flags dictionary.

```
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class MyInputRequired(InputRequired):
    field_flags = ()

class SequenceForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name:', validators=[MyInputRequired(), Length(1, 128)])
```

Comment: You could simply reset the tuple of flags to be set: `class MyInputRequired(wtforms.validators.InputRequired):` next line:  `field_flags = ()` (can't get the formatting right....)

Comment: @VPfB That is a great solution. If you want to create an answer for it I would accept it.

Comment: I think it is very similar to your solution. And you came first with the idea.

Comment: Actually it isn' t because validation is transfered from client-side to the view funciton. This way one can skip validation for "cancel".

Answer (score 9):

Since you use Flask-Bootstrap's `quick_form()` macro, you can just set `novalidate` parameter to `True` to disable client-side validation (it will set a `novalidate` attribute to your HTML `<form>` element):

```html
{{ wtf.quick_form(form, novalidate=True) }}
```

If you are using Bootstrap-Flask, the method is similar:

```html
{{ render_form(form, novalidate=True) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could forbid rendering of the `required` attr.

```
class MyTextInput(wtforms.widgets.TextInput):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs['required'] = False
        return super().__call__(field, **kwargs)
```

For Python2 add args like this:`super(MyTextInput, self)`

and then:

```
name = StringField('Name:', validators=[Required(), Length(1, 128)], widget=MyTextInput())
```

Comment: This is a good solution for a specific field type. However if I got multiple field  types in my form I need to create a separate widget for each of them.

Comment: @MrLeeh Yes, that's true. You just have to modify one of the items in the chain (validator, flags, widget, quick_form)

Answer (score 1):

To disable client-side form validation, add the 'novalidate' attribute to the HTML `<form>` element in your template:

`<form method="POST" novalidate>`